# How can one configure OpenLayers to allow unlimited zooming

Tags: zooming, openlayers

We are experimenting with using OpenLayers within a PHP application that displays data from PostgreSQL/PostGIS and GeoServer.

The initial use of OpenLayers is terrific except for one problem:

A lot of our data has very small extent eg < 0.1m.

When we zoom in to look at the features they disappear.

We have read the documentation, looked for examples, tried setting zoom values > 19 but to no avail.

There are NO scale thresholds in the SLD so this is not the issue.

Can anyone suggest how to get around this? Is there a NO-LEVELs mode for OpenLayers as we are not interested in mimicking Google Maps etc.